# "didSelectRowAt indexPath" not getting called when UITableViewController nested in another UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The UITableViewController is nested in a UIViewController as the child view controller, everything is fine, except the delegate method `"didSelectRowAt indexPath"` is not been called when touch the cell.

The cell's `isUserInteractionEnabled = true`. 
Also, after I tried to make the tableView controller **NOT** the child of UIViewController, then `"didSelectRowAt indexPath"` getting called for the same code.

**Below is the code to setup table in the super UIViewController:**

```swift
    private func setupTableView() {
        let tableVC = NewHouseTableController()

        self.addChild(tableVC)
        tableVC.didMove(toParent: self)

        let tableView = tableVC.view!
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.totalTf.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
            ])
    }
```

**Here is the code for child UITableViewController in viewDidLoad:**

```swift
class NewHouseTableController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 44;

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseCellIdentifier)
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: reuseHeaderIdentifier)
    }
```

I'v no idea what happened, when the cell is clicked, just nothing happens, the didSelect method is seems been ignored...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using the storyboard?

Comment: Also, why is that needed? Why don't you simply add a tableView in your main controller? The NewHouseTableController is covering your whole main controller's view, so I don't think there is a need for that parent-child relationship.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the delegate when you add it to the parent view? e.g `tableView.delegate = tableVC`

Comment: First, since your child view controller ***is*** a `UITableViewController` subclass, you don't need to set the `.dataSource` or `.delegate`. Second, I just did a quick test using your code, and `didSelectRowAt` is called as expected. Is there something else in your code (that you haven't shown) that could be the problem?

Comment: @DonMag My mistake, I forgot added a tapGesture for the quit keyboard purpose. After disable the tap gesture, `didSelectRowAt` method getting called again! Thanks !